# Minimal GNU Make build system

Tags: c++, c, gnu-make, dependency-management, build-system

There are few articles on how to avoid autotools for small projects and use the power of bare GNU Make:

1. http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/
2. http://david.rothlis.net/large-gnu-make/

I'd like something that relies on `wildcard` and built-in implicit rules as much as possible.

Are there ready scripts for GNU Make I can use?

The features I need (see the second link for description):

- Provide the standard targets
- Standard environment variables
- Automatic dependencies on C and C++ header files
- Use implicit rules
- Dependencies on third-party packages: pkg-config

Nice to have but non-essential for me:

- Fine-grained dependencies
- Detect changes in environment
- Clean output
- Separate build directory

Comment: We've been working hard upon our make temmplate macros, and I won't just disclose that here. Also there's an ongoing interior company discussion, what should be the right way to go. If not _opinion based_, your question asks for off-site resource recommendation (which both are off-topic).

Comment: It is certainly opinion based and asks for off-site resource recommendation. Is there a stackexchange site for the question to be migrated to?

Comment: May be you get a suggestion on [Meta SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions) ... As mentioned a good starting point to provide some more general stuff in build sysetems, is using [_make templates_](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not aware of any canned scripts one could grab and use. At two separate $dayjob$s I ended up reinventing this same wheel, and implementing a gmake-based build system that, pretty much, implemented every bullet point in your list. On the plus side: although that was a bit tedious, it was still very fun hacking. And, oh, one more that's not on your list: integration with version control (the last one was svn, if I ever do it again, I'll probably end up using git).

Comment: go to github.com, search for makefile, you'll get 1800 or so repos. On the left panel click C or C++, and look around what suite you best

Comment: say, https://github.com/mbcrawfo/GenericMakefile might be good enough

Comment: Put `GenericMakeFile` as an answer. It's a great place to start from, and it's quite feature-rich for 100 lines.

Comment: You forgot: • self-documented Makefile: https://gist.github.com/klmr/575726c7e05d8780505a ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my template library called **prorab**:

https://github.com/cppfw/prorab/blob/master/wiki/HomePage.adoc

It has most of the features you need plus it has feature of including independent makefiles which use the same template library.

Features:

- Provide the standard targets: Provides targets for compiling .c and .cpp files, linking binary, dynamic library or static library. Also provides targets: all, clean, install, uninstall
- Standard environment variables: Supports CC, CXX, CFLAGS, CPPFLAGS, CXXFLAGS, LDFLAGS, LDLIBS, PREFIX, DESTDIR
- Automatic dependencies on C and C++ header files: yes. *.d info generated by GCC is used.
- Dependencies on third-party packages: pkg-config: just pass `` `pkg-config --libs yourPackage` `` to LDLIBS, for example.
- Fine-grained dependencies: yes, everything depends on necessary things.
- Detect changes in environment: supports dependency on compilation/linkage flags
- Clean output: yes, if needed it is possible to turn "full" output on.
- Separate build directory: object files are placed to a separate directory which you can re-define.

Feel free to contact me if any questions or submit an issue with question on github.